# Create a duplicate database in amazon redshift

Tags: python, database, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have a database called as `demo` in a redshift cluster. I want to create a new database called `demo_copy_feb` in the same cluster with all the data in `demo`.
Whats the best way to do this?

Comment: Also: [backup - Is it possible to Clone a RedShift Database? - Database Administrators Stack Exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/55228/is-it-possible-to-clone-a-redshift-database) and [Migrating data from one Amazon Redshift database to another using Amazon S3 | by Julian Alexander Murillo | The Startup | Medium](https://medium.com/swlh/migrating-data-from-one-amazon-redshift-database-to-another-using-amazon-s3-558523cb1bd1)